# Jupyter spam with "Generating new user for token-authenticated request" in logs

Tags: docker, nginx, jupyter

I have jupyter server runnning in Docker using

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook

ARG NB_USER

USER root
RUN apt-get update
COPY apt-requirements.txt .
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y $(grep -hvE "^\s*#" apt-requirements.txt | sort -u | tr '\n' ' ')

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
USER ${NB_USER}
```

here is my .env according to jupyter

```
NB_USER=lab
CHOWN_HOME=yes
CHOWN_HOME_OPTS="-R"
RESTARTABLE=yes
LOCAL_WORKING_DIR=/home/lab
ACCESS_TOKEN=''
ACCESS_PASSWORD=''
```

Web-page is working. I'm using nginx with basic auth as an authentication system. But when I'm trying to run any kernel it's freezed and I see huge amount of the same messages in logs:

```
...
[I 2023-03-24 05:12:15.820 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 9da819445a07428ba5b07d4361b37592
[I 2023-03-24 05:12:21.037 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 331a45f6cce5460687f11897db9e9769
[I 2023-03-24 05:12:26.257 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: fee1b282a03d4b2692cf84019e720206
[I 2023-03-24 05:12:31.461 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: e9f3d5afb7414411bb89f3bdf33db921
[I 2023-03-24 05:12:36.696 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: e37235f5281345478aba2f54432de69a
[I 2023-03-24 05:12:41.896 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 1d9fdf97ba47469bbdac043b061d76cd
[I 2023-03-24 05:12:47.096 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 2775f602543e4e91a7b166a48841e8c5
[I 2023-03-24 05:12:52.348 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: c4b3a0eab9e34ef0b2e09de1c38db603
[I 2023-03-24 05:12:57.545 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 6d1cdbaac5c247719aa2ea5c2cac4ca9
[I 2023-03-24 05:13:02.759 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: c84253281c3147c2990d7ba7359b93bb
[I 2023-03-24 05:13:07.959 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: f186b1d4966d4bf886dec3d9f5844ffa
[I 2023-03-24 05:13:13.188 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 64fcc05713fa441eb9b3bcad5281433c
[I 2023-03-24 05:13:18.384 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 224e24f08a654dc390ffa2696861caa1
[I 2023-03-24 05:13:23.601 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: aa3bef1b7b004e83889741a0ac3c7158
[I 2023-03-24 05:13:28.808 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: f255c769aa304de2b1a41b9aabbdbd44
[I 2023-03-24 05:13:34.014 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: fa7abb6e35eb42cba3c6e642d18cea6f
[I 2023-03-24 05:13:39.215 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 46d7ac3d6fff4880a26d0873587dd155
[I 2023-03-24 05:13:44.419 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 6d23b2e4c9524ea78d7821b3a47f8db2
[I 2023-03-24 05:13:49.624 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 5405124b3b3244c3bcb0aed218d3277b
[W 2023-03-24 05:13:53.034 ServerApp] 400 GET /api/events/subscribe (701491a4151d4b8fad8ba9526a46e9ff@172.16.102.12) 0.98ms referer=None
[I 2023-03-24 05:13:54.819 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: ef027366b79a4392aff548dbfb9bac77
[I 2023-03-24 05:14:00.026 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 903c995330614162ba09c1ae13a57e92
[I 2023-03-24 05:14:05.260 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 831d1c53bbc949c3a7745f72524f34b1
[I 2023-03-24 05:14:10.466 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 8a4d2f6f74ee4d3e8edc05decf764359
[I 2023-03-24 05:14:15.659 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 088e7bda4c514c40b6c5d1737309a021
[I 2023-03-24 05:14:20.869 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 30b53a766f3a4bfca21be730183cc971
[I 2023-03-24 05:14:26.083 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 55e2dd38626d4bc4b1e55b06393361b8
[I 2023-03-24 05:14:31.299 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: c98d4183a07f45d8b396e0edd85182ca
[I 2023-03-24 05:14:36.541 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 5f1d10320a3a42fda710e9413fd27eda
[I 2023-03-24 05:14:41.741 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 1ca84895821f44d4bed13521361f1002
[I 2023-03-24 05:14:46.980 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 483a959a4b2345fab737d191f888842b
[I 2023-03-24 05:14:52.179 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 84753d15f76c4c2cb70366d67c04fcc3
[I 2023-03-24 05:14:57.380 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 175dfe09239548cb889eabe6a0803dde
[I 2023-03-24 05:15:02.580 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 8f583f31f5c54820b0431d9b435eeb84
[I 2023-03-24 05:15:07.842 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 04cca534776b4817bc0fe0091ce02a10
[I 2023-03-24 05:15:13.071 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 138db06f0aa343fdabc946133f7fd8e5
[I 2023-03-24 05:15:18.268 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 4c62df2491404e2fa69d398725d21e63
[I 2023-03-24 05:15:23.472 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 0dbe0057a0464a218ef8016ca9f7e170
[I 2023-03-24 05:15:28.674 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 5a36c1a37316480ebd9864587def8fd1
[I 2023-03-24 05:15:33.887 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 849bf77ff1e9445d9f2ab568d9c48618
[I 2023-03-24 05:15:39.091 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: a26cb196adfa4ce69b17e31aa427c450
[I 2023-03-24 05:15:44.334 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 3804cbba1b4f4059a45ea5ad91227710
[I 2023-03-24 05:15:49.546 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: eb0d83ecb7594ba89944ea4e943eb5f4
[I 2023-03-24 05:15:54.737 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 0baa835fff2c4211b41608b32abb60d0
[I 2023-03-24 05:15:59.937 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 4dc52b7d2ca54717bffe75789db4be1a
[I 2023-03-24 05:16:05.130 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: f3efd62297c84ee59d07e315849d1d54
[I 2023-03-24 05:16:10.330 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 0b460674f8094a8688faa4c93109b697
[I 2023-03-24 05:16:15.530 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 6a2093d84b1a4c578b93a0964e8d6a2f
[I 2023-03-24 05:16:20.749 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: d6c76c336fd0455aa003efc06dd729b1
[I 2023-03-24 05:16:25.953 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 620e157766f645f6b004a386b494d87b
[I 2023-03-24 05:16:31.150 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 41e5d41f81824bbc9720b57e003e8fb9
[I 2023-03-24 05:16:36.394 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 9e0993d57318499c8a6a541d0a6decea
[I 2023-03-24 05:16:41.616 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: f3bd064e04614c01840625f30895d10c
[I 2023-03-24 05:16:46.827 ServerApp] Generating new user for token-authenticated request: 636c5c670e7742ebb0c49f0f1818f7fd
...
```

could not find any info what does this mean and how to fix it. Does this message affect freezing of kernel at all?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at the exact same log message and the one setting in common is the empty token `LAB_TOKEN=""`.
I just tried a random token `LAB_TOKEN="test"` and the log spam is now gone on my side. I didn't have a frozen kernel either way though, so that seems to be an unrelated issue.

Comment: Is `LAB_TOKEN` the same as `ACCESS_TOKEN` ? I have `ACCESS_TOKEN=""` but there are no configs for `LAB_TOKEN`

Comment: Yes, that was just the internal argument passed as the token `--NotebookApp.token=${LAB_TOKEN}`. So this should be the same.

Comment: then I have to enter token every time I'm logging in. The idea was to use only Basic Auth without tokens

Answer (score 0):

(the following assumes one is using Visual Studio Code to connect to a remote Jupyter kernel -- I'm still posting it here in case others find it useful)

Use `jupyter-notebook` command instead of `jupyter-server` to provide the remote API.

The `jupyter-server`/ VSCode Jupyter connectivity is horribly broken.
The latest versions I found which worked:

- jupyter-server: 1.23.6
- VSCode Jupyter extension: 2022.6.1001890150 (worked on VSCode 1.77.0)

Notes:

- It may be good to `rm -rf ~/.ipython ~/.jupyter` when experimenting with the server-side versions.
- My client platform is latest OSX/arm Ventura 13.2.1, server is Ubuntu Server 22.10 x86_64.
- The way to setup a remote Jupyter connection in VSCode 1.77.0 and Jupyter extension version 2023.3.1000892223:

  1. select "Existing Jupyter Server" and enter the URL
  2. restart VSCode
  3. select "Existing Jupyter Server" and select the previously entered server (which now has a visible entry)

Comment: I use a container from DockerHub: https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/scipy-notebook